# Different names of app (iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, xcode, app-store, google-play

Can I have a name on the app on a device and another name on iTunes (the same app)?

What about on Android and Android Market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  There are tons of examples in the App store.  This is very commonly done to make something fit under the icon other than a mechanically truncated version of a longer App store name.  The App store name (entered in iTunes Connect) must be unique.  There is no such requirement on the Bundle Display Name (specified in the app's plist) that appears under the icon.  However it's likely that Apple may reserve the right to reject any name combination that they find misleading (or suspect to be a trademark infringement, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, click on your project, then click on your target. Under the Info tab, look for "Bundle display name". Change this to whatever you want the app's name to be on the device. Make sure it's short enough or it may get truncated - there's limited space below the icon.

Set the app's full name in iTunes Connect when you create the app. It can be longer since it will be viewed only in the app store.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely up to the reviewer that checks your submitted app. Check out the guidlines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html Although there are no mandatory constrains that will oblige you to name the application in the same way in the bundle and online, I'm not sure that Apple will like it if you call them two completely different names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The name on the device (under the icon) is set in your plist file as "Bundle display name". The name in iTunes is set in iTuneConnect.